# Not able to validate Email in Angular using Validators.required

Tags: angular

I am not able to validate Email in Angular using Validators.required as it is also accepting mail@g as valid email.

e.g

'eMail': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.email])]

Comment: Validators.email accepts 'mail@g'?

Comment: Can you provide code example ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your validation with:

```
'eMail': ['', Validators.email]
```

Make sure your input has `type="email"`

Comment: make sure your input is type="email"